# Generate random numbers less then column values

Tags: r

Is there a way to populate random numbers less than values in another column

Example

```
df
ColA
12
324
45
546
```

Expected output (ColB should be less than values in COlA)

```
df
ColA     ColB
12        10
324       150
45         20
546        400
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
set.seed(123)

df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(ColB = sample(1:ColA, 1))

   ColA  ColB
  <int> <int>
1    12     4
2   324   256
3    45    19
4   546   483
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized base R solution might be using `runif`, i.e.,

```
df <- within(df,ColB <- trunc(runif(nrow(df))*ColA))
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- within(df,ColB <- trunc(runif(nrow(df))*ColA))

> df
  ColA ColB
1   12    3
2  324  120
3   45   25
4  546  495
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(ColB = map_int(ColA, ~ sample(seq_len(.x), 1)))
```